# How do I show $f$ is one-one on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a differentiable map (but not necessarily continuous differentiable) with component functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, that is $f(x_1,x_2)=(f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2))$ for all $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. For all $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, one has

$|\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}-2|+ |\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}|+|\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}|+|\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}-2| \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Prove that $f$ is one-one on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I cannot use inverse function theorem to prove this question. Can anyone suggest some direction to solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Assume not, then there are $x_1, x_2, R, \theta$ so that $f(x_1, x_2)=f(x_1+R\cos\theta, x_2+R\sin\theta)$. Let $F: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ be defined by
$$
F(t)=\cos\theta\cdot f_1(x_1+t\cos\theta, x_2+t\sin\theta)+\sin\theta\cdot f_2(x_1+t\cos\theta, x_2+t\sin\theta).
$$
So $F(0)=F(R)$. Compute
$$
F'(t)=\cos^2\theta \cdot \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+
\sin^2\theta \cdot \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}+
\sin\theta\cos\theta \cdot \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}+
\sin\theta\cos\theta \cdot \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1},
$$
then
$$
F'(t)\geq \cos^2\theta \cdot \frac 32+
\sin^2\theta \cdot \frac 32-
|\sin\theta\cos\theta |\cdot \frac 12-
|\sin\theta\cos\theta |\cdot \frac 12\geq \frac 32-\frac 12-\frac 12=\frac 12. 
$$
So $F$ is strictly increasing, contradicts the fact $F(0)=F(R)$.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminaries: Assume $a,b\in \mathbb R^2.$ Then

i) one of $|b_1-a_1|,|b_2-a_2|$ is at least $|b-a|/\sqrt 2.$

ii) Suppose $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable. Then

$$g(b)-g(a) = \nabla g(c)\cdot (b-a)$$

for some $c$ on the line segment from $a$ to $b.$

iii) The hypotheses imply $\partial f_1/\partial x_1 \ge 3/2,$ $|\partial f_1/\partial x_2| \le 1/2,$ similarly for the derivatives of $f_2.$

In our problem assume WLOG $a\ne b$ and $|b_1-a_1|\ge |b-a|/\sqrt 2.$ From ii) we get

$$f_1(b)-f_1(a) = \nabla f_1(c)\cdot (b-a)$$ $$ = [\partial f_1/\partial x_1(c)](b_1-a_1) + [\partial f_1/\partial x_2(c)](b_2-a_2).$$

Taking absolute values and using iii) gives

$$|f_1(b)-f_1(a)| \ge (3/2)|b_1-a_1|-(1/2)|b_2-a_2| $$ $$\ge (3/2)|b-a|/\sqrt 2 - (1/2)|b-a|.$$

It's easy to verify that the last expression is greater than $0,$ which implies $f$ is one-to-one.